# How can I direct light through a hole in a wall?

Tags: lighting

I have a room which has no window, but it has a round hole above the door:

[image]

Concave lens spreads out incoming light:

[image]

Is there a simple way to create a concave lens at home  which sits in the hole and spreads incoming light into it, so the upper areas of the room have more natural light?

Maybe some plastic thingie filled with water? The hole's diameter is 15cm and its depth is 10cm.

I tried putting a plastic water bottle into it, but it did not bring more light, because it's not a concave lens (and too long anyway).

Comment: Where is this "incoming light" coming from? Unless it's direct sunlight or fairly intense artificial light you won't see a useful benefit.

Comment: Check out sun tubes.

Comment: @isherwood the adjacent room has a window as you can see on the bottom of the picture

Comment: Notice that I said "direct sunlight". The light reflecting in from the ground and other surfaces to your high hole isn't going to do you much good at all.

Comment: @SolarMike I did, it's a similar concept, so I want to create a short diy version of it from everyday stuff.

Comment: @isherwood  the window is on the opposite wall in the adjacent room, so it faces the hole

Comment: The sun must be low in your part of the world. Either that or you don't take "direct sunlight" to mean what I (and all other users of the term) intended. You will not collect enough _indirect_ sunlight and pass it through that little hole to light your room in any meaningful way.

Comment: A heliostat (look them up) pointed a the hole would do something for you, when the sun was in its view. At which point you probably wouldn't need a lens, but you'd actually have the "beam of light" your diagram has, and which your hole into the room does NOT have. So a lens would do "something" at that point. A lens will do nothing (actually, it will slightly reduce light transmission) without a beam of light to work with. Best you could do for that hole would be to line it with reflective material (foil or the like.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to construct a dome on the outside, to provide as large as possible of a surface into which the photons will travel. Water is a good idea, but has biological growth considerations as well as high maintenance. Consider optical matching fluid to fill the enclosure you build. Keep an eye out for the old-style projection televisions, which use a rear projection system. There are three CRT devices, one for each color. As part of those devices, the region between the face of the CRT and the projection lens is filled with optical matching fluid. It has the consistency of glycerol, and smells like glycerol, and may be glycerol. You could purchase glycerol/glycerine/glycerin instead.

The portion of the tube that passes through the wall should be silvered if possible, or simply raw acrylic tubing. On the inside, an equivalent dome will scatter the collected photons into the room. You will have constructed what is effectively a light pipe, the concept of which is used in fiber optics.

Depending on the materials you use, you may find you have a viewport to the outside world, inverted and possibly partially focused on the inside dome.

Deviating slightly from any aspect of the above description will only slightly degrade the amount of light transmitted.

Instead of internal and external domes, you could use the lenses from the old television, if the dimensions are matching. I think the lenses I have are closer to 100 mm diameter, though, and you'll likely not find larger ones. Maybe a nice clear glass salad or punch bowl!

Comment: If you put domes on both sides then you get convex lens which focuses light instead of scattering it, right? I think the domes' top should face the hole from each side, because that's how you get concave lens like on the picture in the question.

Comment: A double convex lens will take light rays from one side and direct them to a focal point some distance away from the lens. The dome on the outside will collect the light but it will bounce around randomly inside the cylinder, destroying any concept of focusing. The inner dome will take the scattered light within and move it without.

Comment: The glass salad or punch bowl idea is nice. I thought of creating something from plastic, but it's much simpler to cut a an existing dome to the right diameter.

Answer (score 1):

About 30 years ago , 4 and/or 6 " diameter stainless ducts were sold , with an external dome ,as skylights. The internal surfaces were polished like mirrors. They came in about 2ft sections that clipped together. You might be able to find some on the internet.

Comment: We have such a device in the ceiling/roof of the hobby room. It moves so much light that I often think I've left the lights on in the otherwise dark room.